# special sorting of two array in matlab with comparison

Tags: matlab

I have two array as below.

```
BLoc1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M']
BLoc2 = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
```

and I want output as below.

```
BLoc1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'NA', 'K', 'L', 'M']
BLoc2 = ['A', 'NA', 'NA', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L','NA']
```

Comment: So You want to write `'NA'` if the letter of the alphabet is missing? Which language alphabet? Also, how long? The alphabet doesnt end at `M`. Why only to M?

Comment: Can you explain what you try to do? What did you try?

Comment: Also, note that `BLoc2 = ['A', 'D']` will be `AD` so `BLoc2(2)` will be `D`, but   if `BLoc2 = ['NA', 'D']` then `BLoc2(2)=A`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is just an example. Array can be of any inputs.

Comment: @dmvachhani Your comment doesn't clarify anything. Please edit your question and specify the range of inputs you can have and what rules you use to generate your output. As your question stands now, your requirements could be interpreted as "put a random number of 'NA's in random positions in the original arrays".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're trying to achieve is possible only with cell arrays because otherwise `'NA'` would be considered as `'N' 'A'` i.e. both alphabets at different indexes.

Anyway, following is the code that will help you decide:-

```
BLoc1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M'];
BLoc2  = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'];

%Converting to cell arrays
BLoc1=num2cell(BLoc1,size(BLoc1,2));
BLoc2=num2cell(BLoc2,size(BLoc2,2));

%Union of the two
complete=union(BLoc1,BLoc2);

NewBLoc1=complete;
[~,idx]=ismember(complete,BLoc1);  
idx = find(idx==0);          %finding the indexes where BLoc1 has missing elements
[NewBLoc1{idx}]=deal('NA')   %filling the elements at missing indexes with 'Na'

%Similarly for BLoc2
NewBLoc2=complete;
[~,idx]=ismember(complete,BLoc2);
idx = find(idx==0);
[NewBLoc2{idx}]=deal('NA')

%converting back to simple matrix since that's your requirement in the question 
%but I recommend you to also run the code atleast once without the next two lines too.
NewBLoc1= cell2mat(NewBLoc1) 
NewBLoc2= cell2mat(NewBLoc2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
clc
clear

A = [{'a'} {'c'} {'d'} {'w'} {'e'} {'t'}];
B = [{'e'} {'b'} {'e'} {'d'} {'z'} {'s'} {'x'}];

A = sort(A);
B = sort(B);

i = 1;
while ~(i > length(A) || i > length(B))
    if isequal(A(i), B(i)) || isequal(A{i}, 'NA') || isequal(B{i}, 'NA')
        i = i + 1;
        continue;
    end

    if A{i} > B{i}
        A = [A(1:i-1) {'NA'} A(i:end)];
    else
        B = [B(1:i-1) {'NA'} B(i:end)];
    end
end

n = length(A) - length(B);
A = [A repmat({'NA'}, [1, -n])];
B = [B repmat({'NA'}, [1, n])];

disp(A)
disp(B)
```